# MySql non-trivial select

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, sql-order-by, having

I have table `friends`: `user_id friend_id date`.
It's row means: user_id add another user to friend in some date

I need make request: Get users, for each of their request they have response back.

get all user `x`: for all (x, y, date) => (y, x, date2) : date2 > date

I tried to write request, should it work for all cases?

```
select f.user_id from friend f
group by f.user_id
having 
     (select count(f2.user_id) from friend f2
      where f2.date > f.date and f2.friend_id = f.user_id
      group by (f.friend_id)) = count(f.friend_id)
```

My sql skills is bad.

Comment: Perhaps you could supply sample data and expected results.  One issue with your query is `having` comes after `group by`.

Comment: what result you want ?

Comment: @Bernd Buffen list of users, each of them have for each request to same user, back request from this user

Comment: lets say a user id=1 has 10 request and only 9 with back request. do you want to see this user id=1 ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen I want all users, who have count of requests equals count of back requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i thing that this must be work. it will deliver all user they have all backlinks

```
SELECT
  f.user_id
FROM friend f
LEFT JOIN friend f2 ON 
  f.friend_id = f2.user_id 
AND 
  f2.friend_id = f.user_id
AND
  f2.date > f.date
GROUP BY
  f.user_id
HAVING
  count(f.user_id) = count(f2.user_id);
```

Please let me know if it works for you